# how to do a binary search on a vector to find element with certain id?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search, c++03

I have a sorted vector and now I would like to find elements from that vector that have a certain id. `std::binary_search` just tells me if the element exists, so I use `std::lower_bound`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo {
    int id; 
    // ... more members ... //
    Foo(int id) : id(id) {} 
};

bool compareById(const Foo& a,const Foo& b) { return a.id < b.id; }

int main(){
    std::vector<Foo> vect;
    vect.push_back(10);
    vect.push_back(123);
    vect.push_back(0);
    std::sort(vect.begin(),vect.end(),compareById);
    int id_to_find = 1;
    std::vector<Foo>::iterator f = std::lower_bound(vect.begin(),vect.end(),Foo(id_to_find),compareById);
    if (f != vect.end() && f->id == id_to_find) { std::cout << "FOUND"; }
}
```

This kinda works, but I strongly dislike it that I have to create a `Foo(id_to_find)` to pass it to `std::lower_bound` and then I have to double check if the element I got is really the one I was looking for.

I think I could use `find_if` to avoid creating that superfluous instance, but as far as I know `find_if` is only linear and doesn't make use of the vector being sorted. I am a bit surprised that I cannot find the right algorithm for the task and I am already considering writing my own.

**What is the idomatic way to do this?**

Comment: You should be able to pass just `id_to_find` or `1` instead of `Foo(id_to_find)`.

Comment: You're using the right thing.  If you want it to be easier write a wrapper for it.  You're always going to have to check the return value though unless you throw and exception if the element does not exist.

Comment: @0x499602D2 afaik that wont make a difference, as anyhow a `Foo` will be created even if I dont write it explicitly. (`std::lower_bound` takes a `const T&` )

Comment: @NathanOliver well I just wasnt sure and I am a bit worried about creating an unnecessary instance, as in the real code `Foo` might be expensive to create (I could add a special constructor only for that purpose...well problem solved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to make you life easier.  The first thing is that the comparator does not need to have the same parameter for the first and second parameters.  The requirement is that the first parameter must be implicitly convertible to the dereferenced iterator and the second parameter needs to be implicitly convertible to the type of the third parameter passed to `lower_bound`.

We can leverage this and just take an `int` as the second parameter so you don't have to construct a `Foo`.  That allows us to make a `compareFooById` like:

```
bool compareFooById(const Foo& a,const int& b) { return a.id < b; }
```

And then we can use it now like:

```
std::vector<Foo>::iterator f = std::lower_bound(vect.begin(), vect.end(), id_to_find, compareFooById);
```

<sup>Note that I did add a new function here.  You use `compareById` for `std::sort` so I couldn't just change it as that would break the call to `sort`.</sup>

Now as far as having to check if you have a valid iterator you have a couple options.  You can write a wrapper function that takes a reference to an iterator to populate and returns if it found an item.  That would look like

```
template<typename It, typename Value, typename Comp
bool my_binary_search(It begin, It end, Value val, Comp c, It& ret)
{
    ret = std::lower_bound(begin, end, val, c);
    return ret != end;
}
```

and then you call it like

```
std::vector<Foo>::iterator f;
if(my_binary_search(vect.begin(), vect.end(), id_to_find, compareFooById, f))
    //do something with f.
```

The other option is to throw an exception if the item is not found.  That, in my opinion, is not what you wan to do though unless not finding the item is a truly exceptional case.

Comment: that `compareFooById` is exactly what I was looking for. When I first read your answer I was expecting that `lower_bound` will do an implicit conversion (which is what I want to avoid), but [that seems not to be the case](http://ideone.com/H700ZC). Now I wonder why the requirement "The type Type2 must be such that an object of type T can be implicitly converted to Type2. " exists at all, because I see no need for it and apparently there is no implicit conversion taking place, but that would be a different question

Comment: @tobi303 the comparator could be something like `bool compareFooById(const Foo& a,const long long& b)` and since `T` and `long long` aren't the same it would fail.  Since the implicit conversion is allowed though it is okay.

Comment: yes, I just dont see why it must be implicit convertible, because as I understood it, that implicit conversion isnt carried out but the `id_to_find` is directly passed to `compareFooById` without creating an intermediate `Foo` instance, I might be wrong though

Comment: @tobi303 But if they types don't match then a implicit conversion has to happen.  If I try to pass a `int` to a function that wants a `const long long&` then the compiler makes a temporary `long long` from the `int` and gives that to the reference.  That is why they say `type2` must be implicitly convertible.

Comment: looking at [this output](http://ideone.com/H700ZC) it seems like there is no temporary `Foo` created

Comment: No, no temporary Foo is created.  We're not talking about `Foo`.  Were talking about the second parameter.

Comment: Finally I found out the cause of my confusion. For some reason I thought that in the requirements of the comparater as written [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) the parameter `T`  is the valuetype of the iterator, but thats not the case. `T` is just any type that I want to compare the elements against. Actually just by looking at the signature of lower_bound it should have been obvious...facepalm

Comment: @tobi303 Ah.  That would explain it.  I though you knew that T was the value to find type.  All good then?